# Docker Cannot start container port has already been allocated

Tags: docker

Hi I am trying to run a container inside docker but I am having next message from docker daemon:

> Cannot start container 93da5ea87a67c939ed658022cce334c7c80b6b7b629939f31c11cc6146dd8ca7: port has already been allocated

The funny part is that I run `docker ps` and `docker ps -a` and no instances are there (I have removed all of them), also if I run sudo `netstat -anpl | grep 8080`, there is no process at 8080 port.

The error I think that comes because just before this I cancelled a docker process which bound to 8080 port when it was starting up but not started yet.

The command I was running `docker -t -i -p localhost:8080:8080 <container>`

I have restarted the computer as well, but I don't know what I can do. Any idea?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't there any other service running on that port? What says `netstat -pean | grep 8080` ?

Comment: This looks similar to your issue - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6476

Can you update docker to latest version in your distro and see? Also, version and distro details will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to include `localhost` in your port allocation, e.g:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 IMAGE_ID COMMAND
```

If this does not work, add the following to your **Dockerfile**:

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

This shouldn't be necessary however it is best practice.